Unable to install Windows SDK 7.1 due to .NET Framework 4 dependency issue
I'm trying to follow the instructions in Q: Where can I get Mdbg? to install mdbg.exe via Windows SDK 7.1 using Chocolatey. However, when I run the command choco install windows-sdk-7.1 -y, I get an error message stating that I need to have ".NET Framework 4" installed.
Here's a screenshot of the error:


Windows SDK SetupSome components cannot be installedSome Windows SDK components require the RTM .NET Framework 4, Setup detected a pre-release version of the .NET Framework 4. If you continue with Setup, these components will not be installed. If you want to install these components, click Cancel, then install the .NET Framework 4 from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187668 and then rerun Setup.Click OK to continue.

I've already tried several approaches to resolve this issue:
1. Running in PowerShell:
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx4Client /All /LimitAccess /Source:X:\sources\sxs
2. Executing Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName NetFx3 -All
3. Downloading and installing .NET Framework 4 directly from the Microsoft website
None of these methods have been successful in resolving the issue.
When I check my installed .NET Framework versions using PowerShell:
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version
I get the following output:
PSChildName                      Version
-----------                      -------
v2.0.50727                       2.0.50727.4927
v3.0                             3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation  3.0.6920.4902
v3.5                             3.5.30729.4926
Client                           4.8.09037
Full                             4.8.09037
Client                           4.0.0.0

As you can see, I already have .NET Framework 4.8.09037 installed, which is a more recent version than .NET Framework 4.0 that the Windows SDK 7.1 installer seems to be looking for.
How can I resolve this dependency issue and successfully install Windows SDK 7.1? Is there a way to make the installer recognize my newer .NET Framework version, or do I need to take a different approach altogether?

Could you set up a Hyper-V Windows VM to see if it works from a fresh Windows installation? Is installing VS2022 Community Edition (it's free for many licensing scenarios) an option to see if it contains an mdbg you could use?

@AndrewMorton do you suspect that having other .NET Framework installations interfering with the process? I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 installed, and doesn't have mdbg.exe as far as I see!

No, I suspect that resetting Windows might be needed to get it into a state where the steps you tried will work. But you might want to avoid that. Seeing as the post you initially refer to is from the year 2010, maybe there is something more modern that you already have installed—what do you want to do with mdbg?

@AndrewMorton I am looking for a Microsoft CLI tool to debug C# .NET

The article MDbg.exe (.NET Framework Command-Line Debugger) has a link to a link to installation instructions. Or you could use the Visual Studio Installer to install the SDK for your version of Windows. (I thought maybe using Chocolatey was a requirement.)

I suspect Windows 7 SDK is incompatible with .NET Framework 4.8, and is actually specifically, looking for .NET Framework 4.0. Why did you install .NET Framework 3.5? Since what your looking to install comes with more recent versions of the Windows SDK I would install them instead of the version your attempting to install especially if your using VS2022 which wouldn’t support the Windows 7 SDK anyway. “ Is there a way to make the installer recognize my newer .NET Framework version” - No
